# SQL most popular

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with items in relation to their order.

---

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `sqltest`;
USE `sqltest`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testdata`;
CREATE TABLE `testdata` (
  `orderID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtyOrdered` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellingPrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `testdata`(`orderID`,`itemID`,`qtyOrdered`,`sellingPrice`) 
values ('1','a',1,'7.00'),('1','b',2,'8.00'),('1','c',3,'3.00'),('2','a',1,'7.00'),('2','c',4,'3.00');
```

---

Intended Result:

A = (1+1)2

B = 2

C = (2+4)6 <- most popular

---

### How do I add up all the qty's for each item and result the highest one?

It should be fairly strait forward but I'm new to SQL and I can't work this one out :S

Solution needs to be mysql and or php.

I guess there needs to be some sort of temporary tally variable for each item ID,
but that seems like it could get messy with too many items.

---

### ANSWER:

(thanks nuqqsa)

```
SELECT itemID, SUM(qtyOrdered) AS total FROM testdata GROUP BY itemID ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT itemID, SUM(qtyOrdered) AS total FROM testdata GROUP BY itemID ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT itemID, SUM(qtyOrdered) as blah FROM sqltest GROUP BY itemID ORDER BY blah DESC` should do it

Comment: gives me an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax"
probly cuz count() is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      *
FROM        testdata
ORDER BY    SUM(gtyOrdered) DESC
GROUP BY    itemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( qtyOrdered ) AS sum_ordered, itemID
FROM testdata
GROUP BY itemID
ORDER BY sum_ordered
```

Answer (score -4):

```
select count(qtyOrdered), qtyOrdered from testdata group by qtyOrdered
```

Comment: this won't give the expected result, because it isn't ordered by the total amount - it will give the item with the bigest single amount at first and so on...